# How to append div by id using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do infinite scroll with a bunch of products. I would like to append a div with id products when I get near the bottom of the page. I am trying this but this will not work

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
    $('#container').append(('#products'));
  }
});
```

it just outputs the word products.

as a side note how can i make it so the id contains a number in it. for exmaple

```
$('#container').append(('#products[i]'));
```

where i is a number that goes up.

Comment: take a look to [jQuery.escapeSelector](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) and [To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name,....](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: _"it just outputs the work products"_ - No, it will add the text `#products` because that's not how [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) works. The first argument has to be a _"DOM element, text node, array of elements and text nodes, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements."_ and not a selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forked from @Vilsad P P ... you are still adding the element handle and not the content in the element ... 
This one adds the actual content:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - 
    $(window).height() - 10) {
        $('#container').append($('#products').html());
    }
});
```

`$('#products').html()` is the content in the element but `$('#products')` is just a reference to the element

Now for appending by id, you can do this:

```
var count = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
        var elem = "#products" + count;
        $('#container').append($(elem).html());
        count++;
    }
});
```

What this does is it takes a variable with a string that matches an actual element, and if the string is a valid selector, for example: `$("#products0")` , then it will return true.
Very legal.

Answer (score -1):

try the below

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      $('#container').append($('#products'));
   }
});
```

you where just adding the text instead of the actual element.